# Which convention is better in C programming?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My question refers to the topic of C pointers. Imagine the following scenario:
I have a struct variable named "stc" defined like this:

```
struct stc {
       int data;
       char ch;
}
```

declared in the beginning of the Main() function in my program. I would like to set the values 
the fields in the struct (i.e. *data*) using a function.

Now my question is which of the following convention is better and why?

**Convention 1:**
Write a function the return a pointer of type *stc*:

```
struct stc *func(int d, char c)
{
    stc *tmp = malloc(sizeof(stc))
    tmp -> data = d;
    tmp -> ch = c;

    return tmp;
}
```

and later on free the allocated memory when the structure is no longer needed.

**Convention 2:** Write a function that receives a pointer to the struct and send it the address of stc

```
void func(stc *stcP, int d, char c)
{
     stcP -> data = d;
     stcP -> ch = c;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no definite answer but I'd recommend the second one (although it doesnt' compile atm), which doesn't restrict you to heap-based allocation.

Comment: Use both if you like; it's a free country (at least where I live).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first usage could cause memory leak without care.

The second usage is better, but you use the arrow operator incorrectly, it should be:

```
void func(stc *stcP, int d, char c)
{
    stcP -> data = d;
    stcP -> ch = c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. you're right about the use of the * operator.. i fixed it!

Comment: This also allows initialization of `stc` stack variables, which isn't possible with a function that does malloc(). But in general, both approaches have merit of course and with the allocating function being better if you need an opaque pointer, since it keeps the actual struct private.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have both, or variants of it:

```
typedef struct stc stc;


#define STC_INITIALIZER(D, C) { .data = d, .ch = c, }

stc* stc_init(stc *stcP, int d, char c) {
  if (stcP) {
     *stcP = (stc)STC_INITIALIZER(d, c);  // Initialize with a compound literal
  }
  return stcP;
}

stc* stc_allocate(int d, char c) {
  return stc_init(malloc(sizeof(stc)), d, c);
}
```

So this has the advantage that you may use the same `init` function for `malloc`ed objets as for other variables.

Also note that you had an error in your code, in C you can't use `stc` without `struct` unless you `typedef` it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The first type is more prone to memory leaks. It is a better practise to free the memory from where it was malloc'ed. The second approach looks neat 
and `void func(stc *stcP, int d, char c)` does the intended task of initializing the structure.